# How to see what GitHub sends to an integration?

Tags: github-actions, checkly

I'm trying to get Checkly working with GitHub using its integration with GitHub. It's quite simple to set up, but there's a variable that GitHub is supposed to give it that doesn't end up defined when I run my tests.

I don't know if Checkly is polling GitHub or if GitHub pushes to Checkly when it does a deploy. Looking through GitHub's docs, there doesn't appear to be any way to see deploy events at all (though I suspect I must be missing something here).

So, my question is, how do I troubleshoot this connection? Somebody is using somebody's API for sure, but I don't have insight into how it works.

Comment: Maybe check the webhooks in the GitHub project settings ?
There you can see all payloads sent and the result

Comment: Thanks! I _think_ the deal here is to look at the deployments api route, though that lacks the "environment_url" setting I should supposedly see there.